# Data services - find entity by child value - retrieve some properties only

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-data-services

I'm using WCF Data services with Entity Framework 4.1

I have 2 tables with many to many relationship. I'm trying to get an entity based on a child value.

```
Table 1 (Suppliers) -> ID (PrimaryKey) ,Name ,isEnabled ,Timestamp
Table 2 (Categories) -> RGID (PrimaryKey) , Name, etc....
```

I've tried to to write the URI like this. My goal is to retrieve all Suppliers - Name and Timestamp - that has a Category with RGID = 3.

so far I've done

```
http://localhost/joybaservice/joybadataservice.svc/Categories(3)?$expand=Suppliers
```

now I'm left with the task of selecting the properties I want. Name + Timestamp.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use $select query option. For example with your query above using the expand, let's say I want to get the Name property from the Category, the Name property from the Suppliers and the Timestamp property from the Suppliers. The query could look like:

```
~/Categories(3)?$expand=Suppliers&$select=Name,Suppliers/Name,Suppliers/Timestamp
```

If you want to do this using the LINQ on the client (using WCF Data Services Client library) then you can't add $select (or any other $ query option) using the AddQueryOption, instead you need to express the intent of the query using LINQ (that's what it's for afterall). So for example the above might look like this (depends on the layout of your classes though).

```
ctx.Categories
  .Where(c => c.ID == 3)
  .Select(c => new Category()
    {
      Name = c.Name,
      Suppliers = c.Suppliers.Select(s => new Supplier()
        {
          Name = s.Name,
          Timestamp = s.Timestamp
        })
    })
```

Comment: It's working great from the browser. if I try to use .AddQueryOption("$filter", "CategoryID eq 108")
                        .AddQueryOption("$expand", "Suppliers,Suppliers/VSupplier")                        
                        .AddQueryOption("$select","Suppliers/SupplierID,Suppliers/VSupplier/HebName") I get error Can't add query option '$select' because it begins with reserved character '$'.

Comment: Edited the answer to include LINQ sample.